# How does a WSDL parser decide to generate a void method for a Request/Reply operation?

Tags: wcf, wsdl, jax-ws, contract-first

I have spent 5 hours on this, and I've already been up 30 hours writing this contract-first spec ("aggressive" deadline, ergo stupid) and I cannot see what I'm missing.

I do not want a one-way operation as I expect faults. I have already built a simple WCF service and examined the WSDL that it generates and it *does* round trip to a void method but I've been staring at it so long (and WSDL 1.1 is so annoying at the best of times - roll on 2.0 please) that I can no longer see what the magic trick is.

Can anyone provide some very simple WSDL explaining the magic? I'm targetting both jax-ws 2.2 and WCF 3.5/4.0 with this WSDL. I am hand-writing the WSDL and every time I try to build proxies (in java or .net) it always builds a method with the return message. I'm losing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "void" method doesn't necessarily mean that it's a one-way operation. The two operations below are different:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Process1();
    [OperationContract]
    void Process2();
}
```

The first one is really a one-way operation - any exceptions / faults thrown by the server will not be propagated to the client, while in the second one, although it doesn't "return" anything, if the server throws an exception (e.g., a `FaultException`), the exception will be returned back to the caller.

**Update**: to answer the question posed in the title, the WSDL parser decides to generate a void operation (at least the one used by WCF) if the schema for the output message of the operation is empty.

For example, in the code below:

```
public class StackOverflow_8316567
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Process1();
        [OperationContract]
        void Process2();
        [OperationContract]
        int Add(int x, int y);
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public void Process1() { }
        public void Process2() { }
        public int Add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
    }
    static Binding GetBinding()
    {
        var result = new BasicHttpBinding();
        return result;
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), GetBinding(), "");
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

If you run it and browse to http://localhost:8000/service?wsdl you'll see that:

1. The operation `Process1` (under wsdl:portType/wsdl:operation) only has an input message
2. both `Add` and `Process2` (r/r operations) have both an input and the output messages

Now, the message part for the output message for those 2 operations reference their schema in the imported schema (at http://localhost:8000/service?xsd=xsd0). You can see that:

1. The schema for the response for the `Process2` operation (complex type `Process2Response`) is an empty element (i.e., an empty sequence)
2. The schema for the response for the `Add` operation (`AddResponse`) is a sequence containing one element (an `xs:int` value).

So the processor will generate a `void` method for `Process2` (since it doesn't return anything) and a non-void method for `Add`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but did you even read the question title, or the body? "How does a WSDL parser decide to generate a void method with a request/reply operation" and "I do not want a one-way pattern as I expect faults."

Comment: Yes, I read it. You mentioned that you "do not want a one-way pattern" because you expect faults. I said that just because it generated a void method, it doesn't mean that you can't receive faults - and this is why I added the example. I'll expand the answer with a direct answer to your question, though.

Comment: I tried to duplicate just the empty sequence pattern last night and it still generated a method with the enclosing complex type as the return. I did verify the same way you did earlier this morning and it is indeed as you say, but there's clearly something extra in my wsdl that's f**king it up. Accepted.

Comment: Figured it out - it appears that with doc/lit wrapped, the wrapper element has be in the same xmlns as the message or svcutil won't generate a void method. annoying. wsimport also doesn't like this model.